# How to bind event to element dynamically with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does anybody know how to bind event handler to element if this element was uploaded with ajax? I have js file which is included into page header. Body of the page updated by ajax. I have tried `live()` and `bind()` methods.

Comment: `.live()` [ now superceded by `.on()` ] _should_ work.  Please show some of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `on`..

```
$('body').on('click', 'a.ajaxadded', function() {

});
```

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: -1 for not analysing the question - `.live()` didn't just magically stop working, you know...

Comment: What am I supposed to analyze. There is no code and the code I posted is how you attach a delegate.  Very funny that my answer  which was posted 1 minute prior to your comment is the same.

Comment: then you should have waited until the OP _has_ posted some code, as I requested in the comments.  Simply pointing him at `.on` is unlikely to solve his problem.  Oh, and my comment was before your answer.

Comment: You are right,  your comment was before (I didn't see it).  Is there some issue with my answer?  Is it incorrect?  Will it not work?

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the code, wrong thing is the way of asking the question.